# python3 - check element is actually in list

Tags: python-3.x

for example i have `excel header` list like this

```
excel_headers = [
 'Name',
 'Age',
 'Sex',
]
```

and i have another `list` to check againt it.

```
headers = {'Name' : 1, 'Age': 2, 'Sex': 3, 'Whatever': 4}
```

i dont care if `headers` have *whatever* elements, i care only *element in headers* has *excel_headers* element.

`WHAT I've TRIED`

```
lst = all(headers[idx][0] == header for idx,
                    header in enumerate(excel_headers))
print(lst)
```

however it always return `False`.

any help? pleasse

Comment: So you want to know if all elements in `excel_headers` are in `headers`?

Comment: Hi, @dash, yes i want something like this

Comment: `all(header in headers for header in excel_headers)`

Comment: @rmn yes this works, but what if i want to **raise** error which element in `excel_header` is not found?

Comment: you can check my updated answer below to get the unmatched elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it using sets would be to use [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
excel_headers = ['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']
headers = {'Name' : 1, 'Age': 2, 'Sex': 3, 'Whatever': 4}
diff = set(excel_headers) - set(headers)
hasAll = len(diff) == 0 # len 0 means every value in excel_headers is present in headers
print(diff) #this will give you unmatched elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your list, the results shows you a before and after

```
excel_headers = [
 'Name',
 'Age',
 'Sex',
]

headers = ['Age' , 'Name', 'Sex']

if excel_headers==headers: print "YES!"
else: print "NO!"

excel_headers.sort()
headers.sort()

if excel_headers==headers: print "YES!"
else: print "NO!"
```

Output:

```
No!
Yes!
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: this is a good use case for a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), since you're looking up elements by value to see if they exist. However, for small lists (<100 elements) the difference in performance isn't really noticeable, and using a list is fine.

```py
excel_headers = ['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']

headers = {'Name' : 1, 'Age': 2, 'Sex': 3, 'Whatever': 4}

result = all(element in headers for element in excel_headers)

print(result) # --> True
```

Comment: it still return `False` :(

Comment: @latenight It runs fine here: https://www.online-python.com/7Xz1sw6ClD 
Is there something else you're not telling us?

Comment: And I've updated my answer. How is it any different?

Comment: tthanks ur solution works, but what if i want to raise error which `header` element  is not in `excel_headers`?